# Comparing the multiDrawArrays, using primitive restart and multiDrawElements in terms of performance?

Tags: opengl, glsl, jogl

I want to draw a mass of branches with different shapes, each of which consisting of 4 triangle strips. (Using OpenGL)

So now I'm considering using one of those method calls (multiDrawArrays, using primitive restart and multiDrawElements).

I was wondering which one is more efficient. Is the method multiDrawArrays() equivalent to several drawArrays() in terms of speed?

Does VAO store the vertex info in the RAM while the SSBO store those in the VRAM? If so, is it better to use SSBO rather than VAO considering the performance?

Comment: YOur terminoligy is wrong. You probably mean VBO and SSBO instead of VAO and SSAO. VAOs do at least exist in GL, while SSAO in the realm of graphics just stands for "screen space ambient occlusion"

Comment: Oh, I just corrected it, thank you for the reminding!!@derhass

Comment: I assume that SSBO means Shader Storage Buffer Objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @derhass already pointed out in a comment, some of your terminology is mixed up. A VAO (Vertex Array Object) contains state that defines how vertex data is associated with vertex attributes. It's the VBO (Vertex Buffer Object) that contains the actual vertex data.

I doubt that using a SSBO for vertex data would be beneficial. In general, the buffer types primarily define how the data is used. The graphics pipeline is tailored towards fetching vertex data from VBOs, and many GPUs have dedicated fixed function hardware to pull data from VBOs and feed it into the vertex shader. I can't see how using explicit code in the vertex shader to pull the vertex data from a SSBO instead would be more efficient.

Whether the data is stored in VRAM or SRAM is a different consideration. The only control you have over that is with the last argument to `glBufferData()`. It provides a hint on how you plan to use the data. For example, if you specify `GL_STATIC_DRAW`, you're telling the driver that you're not planning to modify the data, which suggests that placing it in VRAM might be a good idea. Whether it will actually be in VRAM is then up to the driver, and it may decide that based on various criteria.

Functionally, `glMultiDrawArrays()` is equivalent to multiple calls to `glDrawArrays()`. But it can certainly be more efficient. If nothing else, it saves the overhead of making multiple API calls. Each API call has a certain amount of overhead, for example:

- It might pass through a couple of software layers, resulting in additional function calls under the hood.
- It needs to get the current context from thread local storage.
- It needs to do error checking.
- It may need some form of locking to deal with access from multiple contexts in multiple threads (might not be needed for a draw call).
- It needs to check for pending state changes.

The `MultiDraw` calls were introduced to cut down on the number of API calls needed.

Now, whether `glMultiDrawArrays()` or `glDrawElements()` with primitive restart is more efficient, that's impossible to say in general. If you're not already using an index buffer, I would be a bit hesitant to introduce one just so that you can use primitive restart. So my instinct would be:

- Use `glDrawElements()` with primitive restart if you're using an index buffer anyway.
- Use `glMultiDrawArrays()` if you're not using an index buffer.

The real answer, as always, can only be obtained by benchmarking. And it can of course be platform/hardware dependent. My prediction is that you will not see a significant difference in most cases, since both of these allow you to draw a lot of your geometry with a single API call, which should avoid bottlenecks in this area.

Comment: I'd also like to add that the [`GL_ARB_multi_draw_indiriect`]](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/multi_draw_indirect.txt) variants should be considered. In my experience, they are to prefered over the old, non-indirect variant with client-side buffers whenever available.

Comment: @Reto Koradi I searched for some other discussions relevant to this topic. And it seems that multiDraw* calls are not suggested now. I also looked it up in the newest blue book 6th, where I didn't found anything about multiDrawArrays() / multiDrawElements() except glMultiDrawArraysIndirect() that kind of thing.

Comment: I don't think `glMultiDrawArrays()` is deprecated. So if it meets your needs, I don't see a good reason why you shouldn't use it. `glMultDrawArraysIndirect()` might be beneficial if the number of draw calls you want to make with a single call is very large. I always thought they were mostly targeting the use case where the draw call parameters are generated by compute shaders. It does require OpenGL 4.3, which means that it will only work on fairly recent hardware.

Comment: As far as I know, glMultiDrawArrays is poorly implemented and gives no noticeable speedup. Moreover, doing exactly the same with glDrawArrays is trivial. Maybe GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect is worth a try. Why not trying mesh instancing? You only have 4 triangle strips, a single static VBO would be more efficient.

Comment: If using WebGL, this is the only way to efficiently use ubershaders.